# XMLHttpRequest cannot load error issue

Tags: java, ajax, cordova, sapui5

I am using sap api with  cordova application for getting data server using ajax call but I am getting error

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/proxy/http/dt007:8000/sap/opu/odata/…EE_SRV/EmployeesSet?$format=json/EmployeesSet?$format=json&_=1473691885583.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send
>   @ jquery.min.js:4"

And this my code

```
$.ajax({
 url:"proxy/http/dt007:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZAUGEMPLOYEE_SRV/EmployeesSet?$format=json/EmployeesSet?$format=json",
 type: "GET", //This is what you should chage

 cache: false,
 async: false,
 contentType: "application/json",
 success: function (response) {
     alert("success");
 },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
     alert(xhr.status);
     alert(xhr.responseText);
 },
});     
}
```

this is my url credentials username :sapuser password:pass@123

I'm new to this sapui5 with cordova. Please help me and correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are trying to execute this code in a HTML file residing at local file system which results in CORS error.

Quick fix to resolve the issue is to disable web Security in Google chrome and try running the HTML.

Other solution is to deploy it a web app to test in browser. You may not face this issue if you test in device hopefully.